# Did my son get hacked?

Tags: ps3

My son just received a used PS3 system from a good friend who had upgraded.  He was playing Call of Duty last night online.  I was watching him play.  Suddenly he got really upset and started going on about the game being hacked.  I just laughed it off because 1) games are always hacked and you just learn to live with it and 2) I didn't fully believe him as he is new to the game and might just be upset that he was getting slaughtered...

And then suddenly...  My son went from a level 7 to level 55 and all of these guns became available.  And all of the players who started low were suddenly at 55.  And then the game got glitchy and things stopped working...

Did my son get hacked?  Is there a way to fix what was done? Is there something that he can do to prevent it from happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes - that was probably a hacked lobby, Yes - reset the game, No.

Comment: @dly Please don't answer in comments

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Does that look like a full and complete answer to you? Your comment seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Comments aren't meant for answers, complete or otherwise.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer If you want to enforce that, then you've got a lot more posts to comment on.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I'm working on it, thanks. Any more concerns?

Comment: I just want to point out that ***you*** (slash your son) didn't get hacked. The *hosted game lobby* got hacked and that hack was to mess with online game profile data in naughty ways. It's worth pointing out this distinction as your console is fine and no private information (passwords, etc.) was leaked. It's the equivalent of walking into a 7-11 and having some random guy shove ten thousand dollars into your pocket. The money is real, the guy who gave it to you might have done something illegal, but there's no legal consequences for you.

Answer (score 5):

Call of Duty, especially the older games in the series that nobody really plays anymore (although the newer games have it too in some extent) Have hacked lobbies that screw with the game settings in various ways. Everything unlocked, unlimited ammo, fast movement, etc. Naturally some of these "modifications" can mess up the game itself and cause it to crash or just act funny.

I can't promise this, but generally your account will remain "OK", as Activison doesn't really even monitor these games anymore.

Simply restart the game, and try to join a different server (your results may vary).

If it is as bad as I'm guessing... you're most likely better off just shelving the game entirely and trying something else.

Comment: I would say your kid lucked out. My sister got into a hacked Lobby that bumped her down to level -55. She would have to grind XP just to get back to level 1, all without create a class.

Answer (score 3):

This definitely sounds like a hack.

Having played Modern Warfare 2 online for the past few years (ie many years after the game was released), I can confirm that these hacked lobbies exist. Often they will simply level everyone in the lobby up, unlocking all weapons, weapon skins, weapon mods, and every other unlockable that would otherwise take hundreds of hours of play to unlock. This is easy enough to verify - simply look through your son's weapons and see if indeed everything is unlocked.

To see if this was a one-time hack while on the hacked lobby, try joining another game that does not appear to be hacked - is your son still at level 55 with everything unlocked?

If not, then you're fine! You can probably continue playing as normal.

If so, then your son's account was leveled up through a hack. So what are the consequences of this?

Well, on the one hand you'll have everything unlocked. This for some people is a dream come true, since again, what normally would have taken hundreds of hours in game is almost instantaneously accomplished on a hacked server. Further, Activision (or whoever the developer of the particular COD game is) is unlikely to care, as this usually only happens in older entries in the series which they no longer monitor.

However, if you're like me and want to feel the sense of accomplishment from unlocking everything myself, then you'll likely need to reset your online account. There is usually an option to do this in the multiplayer options of the game (though you haven't provided the specific COD you're using, finding the option itself should be fairly intuitive via the in-game menus).

Regarding prevention in the future, unfortunately there is not much to be done. If you join a server you suspect to be a hacked lobby, you can try to leave before any of the more permanent hacks (like leveling up) are done to your profile. Otherwise this may be something you need to get used to.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, he did get hacked. Leave the game, then join back, and if it still is happening, take the disk out and put it back in.

I also use a PS3 and this happens a lot,  but this should work. If it doesn't, take the game to the store and tell them whats wrong.

Comment: Leaving a hacked lobby doesn't fix your account leveling up. Taking the disk out also doesn't help with being in a hacked lobby. There's also nothing the store can do for online profiles.